# Divide not returning the decimal value I expect

Tags: c#, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's wrong with this division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704702/whats-wrong-with-this-division)

If you divide `2 / 3`, it should return `0.66666666666666667`.  Instead, I get `0.0` in double value type and `0` in decimal.

My purpose is to divide even (e.g. `2 / 3`) and round to 1 always to the nearest.

Any help?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're doing integer division, from the sounds of it.  Try this:

```
decimal result = 2.0 / 3.0;
```

Or even force it to decimals for all of the operations:

```
decimal result = 2.0m / 3.0m;
```

This should give you a result more like you expect.

Comment: indeed its integer, dooh haven't thought....thanx, marking as answer as the first one

Answer (score 8):

Doing 2/3 is integer division which will not return the decimal place of the division. To get .666666667 you will need to do 2.0 / 3.0 which are both doubles to get the expected answer.