# Unable to write the equation correctly as it keeps giving me the answer 0 which has to be around 0.4879602393

Tags: equation, equation-solving

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La2WR.png)

so I am new to C# and I have to write this equation but whatever I do, or however I try to break it down, I tried to just use different double names for some parts of the equation like (1 / 4) is S1 and then the rest as S2 S3 S4 S5 and add an Z1 that merges the whole equation together but I always end up with 0 so i guess the equation is just wrong but i cant see where my mistake is.
double c = 10 * (Math.PI / 180);
double Z2 = (1 / 4) - ((1 / 4) * Math.Sin(((5 / 2) * (Math.PI)) - (8 * c)));

Comment: Try to write 1.0 and so in instead and see if it produces the expected result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Divide not returning the decimal value I expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597029/divide-not-returning-the-decimal-value-i-expect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, integer division returns an integer, so `1 / 4` always returns the rounded value of zero. Try division with at least one operand a floating point value, e.g. `1.0 / 4`.