# Arithmetic Operators C# - How to get the decimal points to show when dividing 2 integers

Tags: c#

I would like to ask what should I do to get the decimal points to show when dividing 2 integers.

Here's the details

```
int a = 25;
int b = 3;
decimal div = a / b;
Console.WriteLine("Quotient: " + div); // 8
```

The problem is it only shows

Quotient = 8

But it requires us to output 15 decimal places which values at 8.333333333333334

What would be the proper way to do this?

This topic is about operators and expressions

Comment: ...by not doing _integer division_. Convert one or both multiplicants to a decimal before dividing...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Divide not returning the decimal value I expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597029/divide-not-returning-the-decimal-value-i-expect)

Comment: Do not tag C for C# questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 25;
int b = 3;
double div = (double)a / b;
Console.WriteLine("Quotient: " + div); // 8
```

```
decimal div = (decimal)a / b;
```

Quotient while using decimal type: 8.333333333333333333333333333

```
double div = (double)a / b;
```

Quotient while using double type: 8.333333333333334

Comment: Yes, just cast a to double or decimal...

Comment: decimal and double are different types. Converting to double to do decimal math is a bad idea

Comment: In C# the decimal type is a 128-bit data type suitable for financial and monetary calculations. so that's why I suggested to cost in double

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.

Comment: I am newly started to post here so I am learning how to post in a better way and how to use tools to represent results. it is my try to contribute

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to get `decimal` you should *cast* (note, that `25 / 3 == 8`, when `25m / 3 == 8.33333333...`):

```
decimal div = ((decimal)a) / b;
```

In general case, if you want to print *arbitrary* number of `digits` after decimal point you can loop and build the string:

```
int digits = 8; // number of digits after decimal separator we want to print
int a = 25;
int b = 3;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append(a / b);

for (int i = 0, r = Math.Abs(a % b); i < digits && r != 0; ++i, r = r * 10 % b) {
  if (i == 0)
    sb.Append(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
    
  sb.Append(r * 10 / b);
}

Console.WriteLine($"Quotient: {sb.ToString()}");
```