# Problem with Double and division

Tags: c#, .net, math, double, division

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Ints and Doubles doing division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195060/ints-and-doubles-doing-division)
>   [1/252 = 0 in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621674/1-252-0-in-c)

Hi,

Maybe because it's Friday, but I cannot understand this:

```
(Double)1/2 = 0.5
(Double)1/(Double)2 = 0.5
(Double)((Double)1/(Double)2) = 0.5
(Double)(1/2) = 0.0
```

Why the last operation is 0? :S

Kind regards.

Comment: May be because this is SO,you should not ask such questions.

Comment: That was my question, why is SO

Comment: @Ravi - It's a valid question, although one I'm sure that has been asked before.  I don't see the reason for a downvote

Comment: @Ravi, what is so bad about this question?

Comment: @LittleBobby: If you understand (the need for) `(double)1/2` the last one is obvious too.

Comment: I didn't downvote.Really. :) Just that m little drunk right now. :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because 1 and 2 are integers. The result is 0. If you cast that to a double, it's still 0. This question was asked just a couple of days ago.

Comment: sorry i didn't find it in the related ones... I'll take a deeper search now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621674/1-252-0-in-c is the duplicate I was talking about. It was a bit hard to find through the search because of the not-very-descriptive title. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Everyone's given you the correct answer so far, I'm adding this so other readers don't miss it in the comments.

Use the same rule as regular math.  ***Inner Parenthesis first.***  So in the first example, the 1 is casted to a double before the division occurs, making the result a double (**division of int and double results in double**).  This rings true if it is `(Double)1/2` or `1/(Double)2`.  So in the last example, `(Double)(1/2)`, the `(1/2)` is performed first, int on int, resulting in int.  Then the (Double) casts it to a Double.  Hope this not only helps you but anyone else curious about this question.  I myself have had many times where I had a long equation and literally had to cast each parameter of the equation to a double.

Answer (score 2):

If you divide two ints, then the result will also be int. So 1/2 gives you a zero which is an integer. Then you are casting 0 to double, which is still zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try (double)(1.0/2.0) - that will give the answer you expect.

Answer (score 1):

As already written, the problem is the type. You can use [suffixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271791/declaration-suffix-for-decimal-type/3271831#3271831) to make sure the type is correct:

```
1d/2d=0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `(Double)1/2 = 0.5`
2. `(Double)1/(Double)2 = 0.5`
3. `(Double)((Double)1/(Double)2) = 0.5`
4. `(Double)(1/2) = 0.0`

In first three cases You cast the integer value (thas is default type for number when you do not use suffix or does not contain dot ) to Double and then do the division with an integer value in first case and with double for 2 and 3, in contrast to last (4) case where the brackets change the order of operation first You divide two integers, and after that cast the result to Double.