# Creating an exception, and having it loop back

Tags: c#

So, i have most of it written out and I think I am pretty close but...I need this code to run though the program and if the user inputs anything other than an Integer for it to prompt the Error message "This is not a number", and have it loop back to ask again "Enter a number: " before moving on to the next inputs. I am also trying to figure out how to get the last part where the program divides numbers together to show if the answer like " 10 / 3 = 3.333" instead it shows "10 / 3 = 3"

This is my code...

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number: ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!int.TryParse(input, out int num1))
                Console.WriteLine("Input is not a number");

            //Asking the user for a second number...
            Console.WriteLine("Enter another number: ");
            _ = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!int.TryParse(input, out int num2))
                Console.WriteLine("Input is not a number: ");
        
            // Lets add our inputs together...
            Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1 + num2);

            // Lets subtract the inputs...
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1 - num2);

            // Let's multiply the inputs...
            Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1 * num2);

            // Let's divide the inputs...
            Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

It will show the message, but not loop back for the user to try the input again.

Comment: `_ = Console.ReadLine();` -- you throw away the result of the second `ReadLine()`.  Why do you do that?  Wouldn't you want to do `var input2 = Console.ReadLine(); if (!int.TryParse(input2, out int num2)) ...`?

Comment: Also `10 / 3 = 3` results in `3` when using integer arithmetic.  If you want to use double precision, do `((double)num1) / num2`  See [What's wrong with this division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/704702/3744182).

Answer (score 3):

I would generally create a method to help with the input. One that prompts and reprompts the user until a valid input was made before returning. I'd also give the user and out by typing `q` or `quit`. To do that return a nullable value with `null` representing "quit".

I've also replaced `int` with `decimal` to enable "real" math.

Here's what that looks like:

```
decimal? EnterNumber(string prompt = "", string reprompt = "")
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prompt))
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
    while (true)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("q"))
            return null;
        if (decimal.TryParse(input, out decimal number))
            return number;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(reprompt))
            Console.WriteLine(reprompt);
    }
}
```

Now your code is quite straight forward.

```
var number1 = EnterNumber("Enter a Number: ", "Input is not a number");
if (number1.HasValue)
{
    var number2 = EnterNumber("Enter another Number: ", "Input is not a number");
    if (number2.HasValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{number1.Value} + {number2.Value} = {number1.Value + number2.Value}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{number1.Value} - {number2.Value} = {number1.Value - number2.Value}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{number1.Value} x {number2.Value} = {number1.Value * number2.Value}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{number1.Value} / {number2.Value} = {number1.Value / number2.Value}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I entered `5` & `8` and got this:

```
5 + 8 = 13
5 - 8 = -3
5 x 8 = 40
5 / 8 = 0.625
```

Answer (score -1):

> if the user inputs anything other than an Integer for it to prompt the Error message "This is not a number", and have it loop back to ask again

You never instruct the program to retry the input. Sometimes, simple is best:

```
        retry1:
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!int.TryParse(input, out int num1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input is not a number");
            goto retry1;
        }

        //Asking the user for a second number...
        retry2:
        Console.WriteLine("Enter another number: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();  // <--- also typo here
        if (!int.TryParse(input, out int num2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input is not a number: ");
            goto retry2;
        }
```

> I am also trying to figure out how to get the last part where the program divides numbers together to show if the answer like " 10 / 3 = 3.333" instead it shows "10 / 3 = 3"

You're performing integer division, while you seem to want floating point division:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", num1, num2, (double)num1 / num2);
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah...today is the second exercise...and the classes are good, but the nuances are...not there yet.

Comment: I feel like `goto` is probably not the best solution for this. There are valid use cases, but here a simple `while` would suffice.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num1, num2;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number: ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    while(!int.TryParse(input, out  num1)) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Input is not a number");
       input= Console.ReadLine();
    }
    //Asking the user for a second number...
    Console.WriteLine("Enter another number: ");
    var anotherInput= Console.ReadLine();
    while (!int.TryParse(anotherInput, out  num2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input is not a number: ");
        anotherInput = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Lets add our inputs together...
    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1 + num2);

    // Lets subtract the inputs...
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1 - num2);

    // Let's multiply the inputs...
    Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1 * num2);

    // Let's divide the inputs...
    Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", num1, num2,(double) num1 / num2);
    Console.ReadLine();

    }

   }
```

> I tried to make the least changes in your code to achieve your desired goal but in briefly it doesnt create exception but loop back

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**